# Mongodb update row

Tags: python, mongodb, row

I've the following .json file:

```
  //_id = 59c8c9447c42c82044be5981
  [{
     "A": "First",
     "B": [
        "First",
        "Second",
        "Third",
        "forth"
     ],
     "C": [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four"
     ]
  }, ...]
```

Now I want to update "C", into "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", and not just one Element.

I've tried to update it like this:

```
  client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
  database = client["myClient"]
  x = "59c8c9447c42c82044be5981"
  collection = database["my_model.model"]
  cursor = collection.update(
      {"_id": ObjectId(x)},
      {"A": "None"},
      {"C": "[ 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight' ]"}
  )
```

But I get the following TypeError:

```
 TypeError: upsert must be True or False
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `{"C": "[ 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight' ]"}`should be next to `"A": "None"`, the last "parameter" is used to specify `upsert:true` in case you need it

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!